# how to send dropdownlist value in the begin form to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to pass the selected dropdown list item value to the controller , im able to send the datepicker values but not dropdownlist item values.

view

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {


                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info ">Device Id</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info  dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x=>x.DeviceId).Select(x => x.DeviceId).Distinct())
                            {
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="deviceid_dropdown">@item</a>
                            }
                            </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />

                </div>
            </div>
            }
```

controller

```
 public ActionResult Reports(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate, string deviceid_dropdown)
{

}
```

Model

```
@model List<SmartPond.Models.SmartPondViewModel>
```

viewmodel

```
 public class SmartPondViewModel
    {
        public string Imie { get; set; }
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }
        public string pH { get; set; }
        public string DissolvedOxygen { get; set; }
        public string Temperature { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please display the model that you are trying to bind your form to?

Comment: im trying to pass only the one string value like 1001,1002,1003.....in the dropdown list the values are coming.<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="deviceid_dropdown">1001</a>

Comment: Yes, but you are using MVC (Model, View, Controller), so should set up a class to bind your submission to. That should contain those three parameters (fromDate, toDate, and DeviceID) as properties. The other thing that might be causing your drop down list to not bind is that you aren't using a select list (Select tag with option tags that correlate to a value). Why are you using an action link?

Comment: FYI i have added model details, but i think its nothing to do with modelm because the data already binded to view-dropdown list, jsut need to send the selected item any how. im using action link bez it was coming with bootstrap dropdown so i used that for better look , let me know wat need to take in place of action link.

Comment: You should try utilizing an Html helper to render your drop down list. If styling is moreso your concern, I don't believe you can bind to a div tag for that property. I would instead recommend utilizing generic bootstrap classes (like class="form-control") or CSS styling. If you set up a select list instead, just make sure the id and name fields for the select tag is set equal to Model.DeviceID to ensure it binds.